# How to embed a tag using content_tag in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this to generate a hyperlink for me:

```
<%= link_to "Example", "http://example.com" %>
```

And I want it display in the td tag, so I want to use this `content_tag` to help me:

```
<%= content_tag(:td,"", :class => "example")%>
```

I want the hyperlink in my td, so I have something like this:

```
<%= content_tag(:td,<%= link_to "Example", "http://example.com" %>, :class => "example")%>
```

But I get the Syntax Error, what should I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Inline:

```
<%= content_tag(:td, link_to('Example', 'http://example.com'),
                :class => 'example') %>
```

Or block form:

```
<% content_tag(:td, :class => 'example') do %>
  <%= link_to('Example', 'http://example.com') %>
<% end %>
```